# How do I spread taint to a certain area in Thaumcraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

I'm trying to make taint spread to a certain area in my world, as in, to a small NPC structure. Is there any way I can do this? I even tried using MCEdit to set the biome, but there's no "enter biome ID" thing, and Tainted Land isn't listed.

Comment: the wiki talks about spreading taint and creating taint http://thaumcrafttwo.wikia.com/wiki/Taint

Comment: As I remember, Thaumonomicon "bad science" stuff also has things to spread taint, for now I can remember only Liquid Death, but there is more stuff...

Answer (score 2):

You can create tainted land by throwing "[Bottled Taint](http://thaumcraft-4.wikia.com/wiki/Bottled_Taint)"

> This research is forbidden knowledge (minor). These nasty little vials allow you to create taint patches anywhere you like, by using (right-clicking) them on the ground.
>   Source: http://thaumcraft-4.wikia.com/wiki/Bottled_Taint

Answer (score 0):

From [How Taint Spreads](http://thaumcrafttwo.wikia.com/wiki/Taint#How_Taint_Spreads) on Bayrattack's link:

> A local infection will not penetrate the ground and only infects the blocks on the surface ... The infection also only spreads to the blocks next to other already infected blocks ...  If there are blocks the Taint cannot infect adjacent to infected blocks, the Taint will not be able to spread beyond them. As will be shown later, this can be used to create barriers that can temporarily stop a local infection from spreading. Taint will mostly infect naturally occurring blocks ... Taint will not infect most player-made materials

From this, you can sculpt a "path" of naturally occurring blocks, i.e. dirt, surrounded by man-made blocks, i.e. wooden planks, to the intended area.

Depending on your version of Thaumcraft, you can also research [Concentrated Taint](http://thaumcrafttwo.wikia.com/wiki/Tainted_Discoveries#Concentrated_Taint) and drop it in the structure you want tainted.

Comment: Recommend mentioning that taint nodes, the source of taint, can also be moved to infect an area.  There are also other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Moving a tainted node to the area should do it but it would take time to change the blocks and biome. And since your in creative you should also be able to place tainted blocks.